# Area 51 topbar throws an error when trying to load the achievements

Tags: bug, area-51, top-bar, achievements-dialog

While trying to load the achievements dialog on any area51 page, it shows a dialog with the following error message:

[image]

Browser is Chrome 58.0.3029.96 on Windows 8.1, with HTTPS Everywhere (although disabling the Stack Exchange rule has no effect).